# pygame.error: mixer not initialized How To Fix?

Tags: python, python-3.x, audio, pygame

so I am loading sounds to my game but I am getting this error
 I am using python 3 windows 10

```
pygame.error: mixer not initialized
```

I tried putting  but when I put that I get

```
pygame.mixer.init()
```

when I put pygame.mixer.init() I get this error?? do I have to import something??

```
pygame.error: DirectSoundCreate: No audio device found
```

```
import pygame
import math

pygame.init()

pygame.mixer.init()


# window
window = pygame.display.set_mode((800,800))
pygame.display.set_caption("new World")
#
# error bloccks
erblock = pygame.image.load("error.png")

# trees images
treo = pygame.image.load("tree.png")

# mountains
mounto = pygame.image.load("mount.png")

# platform images
blocks = pygame.image.load("block.png")

# coins image
heart = pygame.image.load("heart.png")

# heart image
heartingss = pygame.image.load("health.png")



# define the shooting sound for the player ------------------------
shootsound = pygame.mixer.Sound("ss.wav")

# hit enemy sound
hitenemysound = pygame.mixer.Sound("hitenemy.wav")


# sound for jumping
jumpsound = pygame.mixer.Sound("sjump.wav")

# pick up coins sound
coinssound = pygame.mixer.Sound("coinssound.wav")

# shoot sound
shots = pygame.mixer.Sound("shootsound.wav")

# hit the ice sound
icehit = pygame.mixer.Sound("h.wav")

# health power UP
powerup = pygame.mixer.Sound("pw.wav")


# load this sound if the player is dead
death = pygame.mixer.Sound("death.wav")

# walking sound
walk = pygame.mixer.Sound("walks.wav")

# background music
music = pygame.mixer.Sound("backgroundsong.wav")
pygame.mixer.music.play(-1)
```

Comment: Can you please edit your question to include OS and Python + PyGame versions

Comment: yah I added it I use python 3 windows 10

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I also faced the similar errors as shown:

```
pygame.error: WASAPI can't find requested audio endpoint: Element not found.
```

What I realised is that I forgot to plug in my headphones to my desktop which means by desktop does not have an audio output device. This results in pygame not knowing where to output the sound (in your case unable to find audio device), resulting in errors to be thrown.

After plugging in an audio device (i.e. my headphones), it works like a charm!